# Has anyone gotten jax-ws-catalog.xml to resolve schemaLocation locally on Metro?

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I have added a jax-ws-catalog.xml to my .war file in order to resolve the schemaLocation locally instead of remotely in .  I've followed the example at

[Metro User Guide: 2.10. Developing client application with locally packaged WSDL](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#developing-client-application-with-locally-packaged-wsdl)

When I deploy the .war and use soapUI to validate the web service it gets stuck trying to access the schemaLocation `http://somehost:8080/CMDB/schemas/common/1.0/CMDBCommonTypes.xsd`

The schema and wsdl both validate in Eclipse (using XML Catalog tool for Eclipse).  (I can post the contents of my jax-ws-catalog.xml and the relevant xsd and wsdl if that will help.

A Google search turns up lots of other problems with jax-ws-catalog.xml not working in the Metro stack.

Has anyone gotten a jax-ws-catalog.xml to work in Metro?

Comment: could you solve this yet? where did you put your jax-ws-catalog.xml file? In my app it looks that way: WEB-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml

Comment: @hubertg: Depending on whether you are writing a client or the server, you put it to `META-INF` or `WEB-INF`. See https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/nonav/2.1.5/docs/catalog-support.html

Answer (score 16):

Where are you placing the jax-ws-catalog.xml and the WSDL files ?

You mentioned that you're using a WAR, but within a WAR the location of jax-ws-catalog.xml depends on whether you're trying to access it as a WS client or as a WS Endpoint publisher (server).

If you're accessing external Web Services from within your WAR, then your jax-ws-catalog.xml needs to go in app.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory, 
Alternatively if you have a contract first web service deployed within your app, and that has the @WSDLLocation annotation, then for that WSDL, jax-ws looks for jax-ws-catalog.xml in app.jar/META-INF

So for client WSDL location app.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml
for contract first WS Endpoints with @WSDLLocation annotation the app.war/META-INF

If you want to do both, i.e. publish (contract first) as well as consume Web Services, then you need to put jax-ws-catalog.xml + WSDLs in both the locations, i.e. app.jar/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF and app.jar/META-INF

I have successfully used the above approach in many of my projects, which simultaneously publish as well as consume web services, and I can guarantee it works as expected.

Comment: You're a genius! I was prototyping with a basic Java application, where the catalog xml was working in the /META-INF dir. But when working with Java web applications, the META-INF directory is not on the classpath. The WEB-INF/classes dir is, and that's why you must create a META-INF folder there, with the jaxws-catalog.xml!

Comment: File should be named `jax-ws-catalog.xml`. The answer is missing a `-` after `jax` and caused me some grief.